# How to get a list of file copied by Net::OpenSSH->scp_get() method

Tags: perl, scp, openssh

I want to copy a dir from remote machine to local. For that, I am using Net::OpenSSH perl module. It is working fine and files are also copied to my local machine. But I want to get the list of files that copied. How can I get the list of files.

I don't want to use Net::SCP.

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Data::Dumper;

my $host='1.1.1.1';
my $credentials={username => 'root', password =>'abc123'};

my $ssh_obj = Net::OpenSSH->new(
                $host,
                user     => $credentials->{username},
                password => $credentials->{password},

            );
ooen $fh, ">/tmp/abc_scp" or die "$!";
my $opts={recursive => 1, glob => 1, timeout => 100, quiet => 1,stderr_to_stdout => 1,stdout_fh => $fh};
my $op=$ssh_obj->scp_get($opts, "/home/ABC", "/tmp/");
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `ooen` statement ;)

Comment: It'll print the files its sending if you enable 'verbose=>1'. Unfortunately you'll have to sift through all the debug statements, too.

Answer (score 1):

Net::OpenSSH scp methods do not allow to do that, but there are other ways:

- Use `tar`:

  ```
  $ssh->system({stdout_file => '| (cd /tmp/ && tar xvzf - ) 2>tar.log'},
               '(cd /tmp/ABC && tar czf - .)');
  ```

  then you will have to read `tar.log` to get the list of files copied.
- Use SFTP via Net::OpenSSH + [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign) (or just Net::SFTP::Foreign):

  ```
  # untested!
  my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(...);
  my $sftp = $ssh->sftp;

  my @log;
  $sftp->rget("/home/ABC", "/tmp",
              wanted => sub { push @log, $_[1]->{filenane} },
              on_error => sub { push @log if $_[1]->{filename} eq $log[-1] });
  ```
- Use the [development version](http://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SSH-Any) of [Net::SSH::Any](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny) that can run on top of Net::OpenSSH:

  ```
  my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new($host, ..., backend => 'Net::OpenSSH');
  my @log;
  $ssh->scp_get({recursive => 1, action_log => \@log}, "/home/ABC", "/tmp");
  ```

  Net::OpenSSH does not implement the SCP protocol itself but uses OpenSSH `scp` binary which unfortunately does not return the list of files copied. Net::SSH::Any has its own implementation of SCP written in Perl and so can do that and more things. Eventually, once the SCP implementation on Net::SSH::Any becomes mature, I will probably backport it to Net::OpenSSH.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using just `rsync` and password-less key-based ssh instead, and simply call it from Perl. It will give you following benefits:

- Very fast sync time on second and further attempts. It will even restart partial downloads of huge files.
- Not very dependent on Perl or it's sometimes weird modules behavior (don't get me wrong - I love Perl, but everything has its place).
- You can do recursive sync and delete old local files:

  ```
  rsync -av --delete --progress --partial --stats \
        user@host:/src/dir/ dst/dir/
  ```
- You will get list of synced files ( using option `-v` - verbose ).
- You can get some sync stats with rsync option `--stats`.
- You can limit network bandwidth used by sync process with `--bwlimit` option.
- You should never embed passwords (especially root!) into your scripts. Configure password-less ssh and sleep better. `rsync` will make use of it.

Comment: I can't use your suggestion because 
I don't want to use system call.
Some of my machine is not having rsync command.